# No container asset found in /assets/containers. Tag Manager's event handler WILL NOT be installed (no container loaded)

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to add Google Tag Manager to my android app.
I have followed [instructions](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/) which includes Firebase, and I've got this error:

```
10-19 18:15:24.637 2503-2538/com.owox.number3.number3 W/GoogleTagManager: No container asset found in /assets/containers. Checking top level /assets directory for container assets.

10-19 18:15:24.638 2503-2538/com.owox.number3.number3 W/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager's event handler WILL NOT be installed (no container loaded)
```

[image]
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
PS: I used Android Studio to create my test app and to connect some firebase features to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, the right answer is:
app -> src -> main -> assets -> containers
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7fjg.jpg)